# Load native npm x509 package using webpack in serverless

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, webpack, openssl, serverless

I'm testing the aws iot features using serverless framework. So for one usecase I wasn't to analyse the x509 certificates iot devices register with aws from aws lambdas, I saw npm package named `x509` to do it easily. It's a native package, so I'm building it in Ubuntu 64 bit box to make it compatible with aws environment.

Issues is the webpack is not identifying this npm package even after my package importing it.

The error it saying is,

```
$ sls package

Serverless: Bundling with Webpack... Time: 245ms Built at: 05/05/2018 11:04:55 AM
                       Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
               jitr/index.js  11.9 KiB       0  [emitted]  jitr/index jitr/build/Release/x509.node  44.2 KiB          [emitted] Entrypoint jitr/index = jitr/index.js [0] ./jitr/index.js 7.39 KiB {0} [built] [1] external "aws-sdk" 42 bytes {0} [built] [2] ./jitr/node_modules/x509/index.js 1.29 KiB {0} [built] [3] external "fs" 42 bytes {0} [built]

ERROR in ./jitr/node_modules/x509/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './build/Release/x509' in '/home/serverless/jitr/node_modules/x509'  @ ./jitr/node_modules/x509/index.js 1:11-42  @ ./jitr/index.js

  Error --------------------------------------------------

  Webpack compilation error, see above

     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Forums:        forum.serverless.com
     Chat:          gitter.im/serverless/serverless

  Your Environment Information -----------------------------
     OS:                     linux
     Node Version:           8.10.0
     Serverless Version:     1.26.1
```

My package dir structure is,

```
- myproject
-- webpack.config.js
-- serverless.yml
-- jitr
--- index.js <- Here I'm importing x509
--- node_modules
---- x509
----- index.js <- First line: var x509 = require('./build/Release/x509')
----- build/Release/x509.node
```

My webpack config file

```
const path = require("path");
const slsw = require("serverless-webpack");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: slsw.lib.entries,
    target: "node",
    output: {
        libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, ".webpack"),
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: "json-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.node$/,
                loader: "node-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    mode: "none",
    externals: [
        nodeExternals({
            whitelist: ["x509"]
        })
    ],
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {
                from: "jitr/node_modules/x509/build/Release/x509.node",
                to: "jitr/build/Release/x509.node",
                toType: "file"
            }
        ])
    ]
};
```

What might be going wrong here ?. I was looking for more debugging steps when doing webpack command, but here i'm using a serverless plugin named `serverless-webpack` to package and deploy the lambdas.

Aws lambda have access to raw `openssl` command, if nothing works I have to use that command from nodejs to do the things.